# Timeline .NET Error

Tags: asp.net, timeline, simile

I worked with the simile timeline a few years back and I am excited to see that it has moved into the [.NET world](http://timelinenet.codeplex.com/). However, when I get it all set up and try doing the example on this site, I get an alert with this error:

"Failed to load data xml from /TimelineData.ashx?Dataid=4123ea6c-3c1b-482c-b8f6-24a9c2fe7465&type=rss
Not Found

It does load the timeline itself properly, but it doesn't load any dates from my codebehind or rss feed from the example. However, the test project worked as expected when I downloaded the latest source code. I didn't notice a file with the name TimelineData.ashx anywhere in the latest source code, and yet it ran fine. If I copy the cc1:Timeline directly from the Default.aspx file in the TimelineTest project, I get the same results, the above popup dialog error.

It kind of seems like support on their site has fallen off, I was just wondering if anyone out there is familiar with this control and could give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems that you did not have setup the web.config to accrept the ashx for time line

Read this page for details
http://timelinenet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation&referringTitle=Home

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<httpHandlers>
<add verb="*" path=".ashx" type="TimelineNet.TimelineAjaxHandler, TimelineNet" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I've tried that, which breaks because apparently the verb value must be at least one character. I also tried using verb="*", as well as what was in the test project '<add verb="GET" path="TimelineData.ashx" type="TimelineNet.TimelineAjaxHandler, TimelineNet"/>' and same results each time.

Comment: @Will try with the verb="*" validate="false"

Comment: Still not working. [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?dt7it7c1xasieao) For reference I'm linking my zipped source code.  I'm wondering the issue might be that the example appears to be in .NET 3.5 and I'm running 4.0?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

The fix!  IIS versions 7 and greater
put the handler in the system.webServer, NOT the system.web.
EDIT: formating.

```
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
            <add name="ashx" verb="GET" path="TimelineData.ashx"         
               Type="TimelineNet.TimelineAjaxHandler, TimelineNet"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```